# Is Hartman-Grobman necessary or enough? projection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm just starting to read about topological conjugacy and stability, and I have the following question.  Suppose I have the following $2$-dimensional system

$$\dot{x} = F(x)$$ with $x_1(0) \ne 0$ where $x(t) = (x_1(t),x_2(t))$ is a trajectory in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth function.  Suppose that $F(0) = 0$, meaning $0$ is an equilibrium point of the system, and that the Jacobian matrix $A = DF(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \mu
\end{bmatrix}$, so that it has eigenvalues $\lambda > 0 > \mu$.  From $\lambda > 0$, it follows that $0$ is an unstable equilibrium point of the linearization $\dot{y} = DF(0)y$.

Question: In general, is it true that $\liminf_{t \geq 0} |x_1(t)| > 0$? My guess is no--even though the Hartman-Grobman theorem implies that the nonlinear system $\dot{x} = F(x)$ is topologically conjugate to the linearized system around $0$, we don't know how $x_1$ and $x_2$ interact in the nonlinear system.  I can't think of a counterexample though.

Comment: In the linear system, the solution $(0,e^{μt})$  converges to $(0,0)$ for $t\to+\infty$. In the non-linear system, there will be a solution curve close-by with this property. Points on this curve could have a non-zero first coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible to have $x_1(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ for all trajectories.
You could have a phase portrait that looks something like this:

[image]